# Как из SVG получить path

Tags: html, svg

Нужно вставить в верстку иконку `SVG` такого формата, где обязательно есть `PATH`. Но у меня в коде его нет:

Мой код:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   id="svg8"
   version="1.1"
   viewBox="0 0 6.3499999 6.3499999"
   height="6.3499999mm"
   width="6.3499999mm">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     transform="translate(-73.176193,-137.34285)"
     id="layer1">
    <image
       width="6.3499999"
       height="6.3499999"
       preserveAspectRatio="none"
       xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJ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"
       id="image3707"
       x="73.176193"
       y="137.34285" />
  </g>
</svg>
`
```

В инете не нашел как это сделать. Спрашиваю экспертов. Помогите, люди добрые!

Answer (score 2):

У вас изображение svg в формате `base64`. Скорее всего в `Inkscape` была встроена растровая картинка, поэтому получить path из этого файла невозможно.

Comment: Действительно, так и есть. В Inkscape перевел в вектор. Все получилось, спасибо!